# PhpStorm shows protected properties in autocomplete

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

For some reason PhpStorm IDE shows autocomplete options for **protected** properties. Am I doing something wrong? I'm developing a package so this is a big issue for me, I want autocomplete to be useful.

Are my IDE settings to blame, is it a bug, or is there something I can do in code to fix it?

Please, review following images of my issue:

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Comment: Can you please provide a code example that reproduces the problem. I'm talking about a project/a folder with needed files) that will clearly show the issue (zip it, upload to Google Drive or alike and share the link ... or some public GitHub repo).

Comment: The first thing is to confirm that there is a reproducible problem (that can be seen not just on your PC only), then check for the possible reasons. It could be an issue in your code, could be caused by some misbehaving plugin, could be some IDE cache/indexes issue.

Comment: What's your IDE version exactly (the full 3 parts of the IDE versions, e.g. latest stable is 2021.3.2)? Try this: 1) Is it reproducible in another empty/basic skeleton project with minimal code? 2) Disable ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE, let it reindex and see if the issue persists. If the issue is gone -- enable 1-2 plugins at a time and restart the IDE until you find the problematic one. 3) Try `File | Repair IDE...` and go step by step. One of them will be `File | Invalidate Caches...` and maybe even resetting the settings (it makes the backup first)